# Entity Framework - table naming conflicts Application, User, Role

Tags: entity-framework

We are in the database design phase of a project using EF4/5 (and RIA Services to Silverlight).

Our current schema has tables like:  Applications, Users and Accounts

In .NET I get naming conflicts to existing objects , and have to specify my own object eg: System.Windows.Application

```
EntityQuery<Customer.Web.Application> queryApplicationT32 = custDomainContext.GetApplicationsQuery();
```

Question: Is it best practice to do this, or to map in EF to something else eg CustApplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Application`, `User` and `Account` are real meaningful names in your domain, you should use them.

You will only have a name conflict when you have using statements for both classes:

```
using Customer.Web;
using System.Windows;
```

If you only use one of them you won't have a conflict. If you use both, you will have to fully specify your class name.

You can also use an [alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): `using myAlias = Customer.Web;` That way you can specify which class to use by using a shorthand alias.

Comment: Thanks - good to have a sanity check.  Think I'll go with full path naming until an alias becomes necessary.